# Iterate over some chunks of data starting with certain strings

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I have worked on a program that could count the numbers of letters in a give data set, which start with `>chrome` followed by long chains of letters `(a,b,c,d at random)`.
The chunks of data exactly look like this:

`("\n" shows space in the command line):
    ">chrome0001"\n"abcdbadbcbdabdcbdbbbbadbcbbdab>chrome0011"    \n"bbbbadbcbabdbaaaadbcbddcdda>chrome0111"\n" ....
(the total number of ">chrome" is 10)."`

I want to count the numbers of letters that appear after each `>chrome`. And expected output should be like:

`>>chrome0001
a:4 b:6 c:10 d: 11`

I've been thinking about whether I could use `\n` and `>chrome` to get the program working but got stuck and studied many questions and answers on this website only to dig a hole deeper... can anybody help me with this, please?

Comment: Could you please describe your input and your desired output so that we can figure out what you need?

Comment: Sure, thanks. I want to print each >chrome tag and the number of letters under the tag. All I want to know is how to iterate over the counting process every time >chrome is encountered.

Comment: `<chrome` doesn't appear anywhere.

Comment: Oh, that was a typo. I edited it again so that no <chrome appears in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a relatively straight forward parsing problem.  First, you want to split the string on the `chromeXYZ\n` bits and group it with the following string.  We can do this fairly easily with regular expressions -- Here's one that works if I understand your input correctly:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = ">chrome0001\nabcdbadbcbdabdcbdbbbbadbcbbdab>chrome0011\nbbbbadbcbabdbaaaadbcbddcdda>chrome0111\n"
>>> re.findall(r'(>chrome\d+\n)([^>]+)', s)
[('>chrome0001\n', 'abcdbadbcbdabdcbdbbbbadbcbbdab'), ('>chrome0011\n', 'bbbbadbcbabdbaaaadbcbddcdda')]
```

The regular expression is straight forward (at least as far as regex go ...):

- `(>chrome\d+\n)` -- ">chrome", some numbers, and a newline
- `([^>]+)` -- Matches all characters until the next `>` or the end of the input.

From here, counting the number of characters in the subsequence is fairly easy.  You can use a `collections.Counter` to do the heavy lifting:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> for chrome, alpha in re.findall(r'(>chrome\d+\n)([^>]+)', s):
...   print(chrome, Counter(alpha))
... 
('>chrome0001\n', Counter({'b': 14, 'd': 7, 'a': 5, 'c': 4}))
('>chrome0011\n', Counter({'b': 10, 'a': 7, 'd': 7, 'c': 3}))
```

Comment: @AaronTaggart -- FWIW, it wasn't added until python2.7 (which has been around for a few years now, but definitely not for most of the language's lifetime :)